# How to determine if mouse is not over an element?

Tags: javascript

I know that there are many similar questions, but I can't understand what is the mistake in my if statement.

So basically I want to stop clicking `nextBtn` once I hover over `timeoutArea`, 
 but this: `timeoutArea.mouseover != true` doesn't seems to work.

```
const timeoutArea = document.getElementById("slider");

    var time = 1;

    let interval = setInterval(function() { 
        if (time <= 20 && window.pageYOffset < 393) { 
            if (timeoutArea.mouseover != true) {
                nextBtn.click();
            };
            time++;
        }
        else { 
            time = 1;
        }
    }, 2000);
```

Comment: The `mouseover` property is `undefined`. Elements don't have such a property. A solution would be to bind event handlers to `timeoutArea` that would set a variable to `true` and you would check that variable instead of `timeoutArea.mouseover`.

Comment: @Felix Kling, Can you demonstrate an example, please? I've tried to find on the Internet how to bind event handlers, but still don't understand, should I use ```.bind()```?

Comment: This is good resource to learn about event handlers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events

Answer (score 0):

if u are using jquery u can use `$('#slider').is(':hover')` in if statement.

if u use only pure javascript u can use with one function

example fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/9x5hjpk3/

```
function isHover(e) {
  return (e.parentElement.querySelector(':hover') === e);
}
```

so change

```
 if (timeoutArea.mouseover != true) {
     nextBtn.click();
 };
```

to

```
 if (!isHover(timeoutArea)) {
       nextBtn.click();
 };
```

Comment: Generally if a question is not tagged with a specific library you should assume that they are not using that library and not suggest a solution based on it (or at least offer an alternative solution).